# Adding class to link_to causes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, slim-lang

I have a sign up with facebook text link in my app.
I tried to add class to this text link to turn this into a button.

In rails it's written like this to display that text.

```
= link_to_session
```

So, as a rule I added the following

```
= link_to_session 'sign up', class: 'button button-primary'
```

but it gave me an error...

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
```

How could I fix this...?
Thank you for your time!

UPDATE
sorry.. I'm not quite sure where to look at...

I looked at session controller and in controller following is written...

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    user = User.find_by_auth(auth)
    if user.blank?
      if session[:user_id].present?
        # via token
        user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        user.definitive_by(auth)
      else
        # new user
        user = User.find_or_create_by_auth(auth)
      end
    else
      user.token = auth.credentials.token
      user.save!
    end
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  def create_via_token
    session[:user_id] = params[:user_id]
    redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

Comment: Where did you get the method `link_to_session`? Can you post this method please.

Comment: Hi Hassanin Ahmed, I just updated the details! Hope this helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
= link_to 'sign up', "write your path here", class: 'button button-primary'
```

Here session path should be present in your route.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! I tried and I got this...

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: What you want to perform on this link?

Comment: This is the sign up with facebook button. When user click this link, it jumps to facebook Oauth page and once fb users accepts it, it will login to my service and jumps users to their MYPAGE

Comment: ok, so copy that facebook path instead of new_session_path, r u using any gem for it?

Comment: yes, i am using omniauth and omniauth-facebook for this.

Comment: ok, refer with https://richonrails.com/articles/facebook-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails & correct your routes path